# Stopping multiple AWS RDS instances using lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds

I would like to stop multiple RDS instances using the lambda function. The code I am using is:

```
import sys
import botocore
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
def lambda_handler(event, context):
   rds = boto3.client('rds')
   lambdaFunc = boto3.client('lambda')
   print('Trying to get Environment variable')
   try:
       funcResponse = lambdaFunc.get_function_configuration(
           FunctionName='lambdaStopRDS'
       )
       DBinstance = funcResponse['Environment']['Variables']['DBInstanceName']
       print('Stopping RDS service for DBInstance : ' + DBinstance)
   except ClientError as e:
       print(e)
   try:
       response = rds.stop_db_instance(
           DBInstanceIdentifier=DBinstance
       )
       print('Success :: ')
       return response
   except ClientError as e:
       print(e)
   return
   {
       'message' : "Script execution completed. See Cloudwatch logs for complete output"
   }
```

I am adding the following environment variables:

> **Key**: DBInstanceName
> **Value**: database-1, database-2

and getting the following error:

```
Trying to get Environment variable
Stopping RDS service for DBInstance : database-1, database-2
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the StopDBInstance operation: Invalid database identifier:  database-1, database-2
```

Here, Keys must be unique, so I can not add another key with same name and add another RDS.
Is there any way to stop multiple RDS instances within same VPC/region without tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[stop_db_instance](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.stop_db_instance) takes **only one db id**, not multiple ones. However, you are trying to pass two of them `database-1, database-2`. So you have to do in a **loop**. For example:

```
   try:

       db_ids = [v.strip() for v in DBinstance.split(',')] 

       for db_id in db_ids:
           response = rds.stop_db_instance(
               DBInstanceIdentifier=db_id
           )
           print('Success :: ')

       return response
   except ClientError as e:
       print(e)
```